# Transferring factor properties between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I've built a predictive model that uses a large number (30 or so) of independent factor variables.  As the dataset I'm using is much larger than the RAM of my machine, I have sampled it for both my training and test sets.

I am now looking to use the model to make predictions over the entire dataset.  I'm pulling in the dataset 1 million rows at a time, and each time, I find new levels for some of my factor variables that were not in my training and test set, therefore preventing the model from making predictions.

As there are so many independent factor variables (and so many overall observations), correcting each case by hand is becoming a real pain.

One additional wrinkle to be aware of: there is no guarantee that the order of variables in the overall dataframe and the training/test sets are the same, as I do pre-processing on the data that changes their order.

As such, I'd like to write a function that:

1. Selects and sorts the columns of the new data based on the
   configuration of my sampled dataframe
2. Loops through the sampled and new dataframe and designates all factor levels in the new 
   dataframe that do not exist in their corresponding column in the
   sample dataframe as `Other`.
3. If a factor level exists in my sample but not the new dataframe, create the level (with no observations assigned to it) to its corresponding column in the new dataframe.

I've got #1 together, but don't know the best way to do #2 and #3.  If it were any other language, I'd use `for` loops, but I know that's frowned upon in R.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
sampleData <- data.frame(abacus=factor(c("a","b","a","a","a")), montreal=factor(c("f","f","f","f","a")), boston=factor(c("z","y","z","z","q")))
dataset <- data.frame(florida=factor(c("e","q","z","d","b", "a")), montreal=factor(c("f","f","f","f","a", "a")), boston=factor(c("m","y","z","z","r", "f")), abacus=factor(c("a","b","z","a","a", "g")))

sampleData
  abacus montreal boston
1      a        f      z
2      b        f      y
3      a        f      z
4      a        f      z
5      a        a      q

dataset
  florida montreal boston abacus
1       e        f      m      a
2       q        f      y      b
3       z        f      z      z
4       d        f      z      a
5       b        a      r      a
6       a        a      f      g

sampleData <- sample[,order(names(sampleData))]
dataset <- dataset[,order(names(dataset))]
dataset <- dataset[,(colnames(sampleData)]
```

Below is what I would want `dataset` to look like once this function is complete (I don't really care about the final ordering of the columns in `dataset`; I'm just thinking its necessary for the loop (or whatever you guys deem best) to work. Notice that the column `dataset$florida` is omitted:

```
dataset
  montreal boston abacus
1   f      Other  a
2   f      y      b
3   f      z      Other
4   f      z      a
5   a      Other  a
6   a      Other  Other
```

Also note that in `dataset`, the 'q' level for `boston` does not appear, although it does appear in `sampleData`.  Therefore, the levels will differ if we omit 'q' from the factor in `dataset`, meaning that in 'dataset', we need `boston` to include the level `q`, but to have no actual observations assigned to it.

Last, note that as I'm doing this on 30 variables at a time, I need a programmatic solution and not one that reassigns factors by using explicit column names.

Comment: Pragmatically speaking if you are randomly sampling 1e6 rows and a factor is only showing up occasionally then it's no use for training methinks. Unless you are doing outlier detection you maybe better filtering them out??

Comment: I've done this over the training/test sets. However, now I'm predicting on the entire dataset, which includes these infrequently occurring factor variables.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it might work.

From this function, the new levels returned for the `boston` column are `Other y z q`, even though there are no values for the level `q`.  Regarding your comment in the original question, the only way I've found to effectively apply new factor levels is also with a `for` loop like you, and it's worked well for me so far.

**A function**, `findOthers()` **:**

```
findOthers <- function(newData)  ## might want a second argument for sampleData
{
      ## take only those columns that are in 'sampleData'
    dset <- newData[, names(sampleData)]
      ## change the 'dset' columns to character
    dsetvals <- sapply(dset, as.character)
      ## change the 'sampleData' levels to character
    samplevs <- sapply(sampleData, function(y) as.character(levels(y)))
      ## find the unmatched elements
    others <- sapply(seq(ncol(dset)), function(i){
        !(dsetvals[,i] %in% samplevs[[i]])
    })
      ## change the unmatched elements to 'Other'
    dsetvals[others] <- "Other"
      ## create new data frame
    newDset <- data.frame(dsetvals)
      ## get the new levels for each column
    newLevs <- lapply(seq(newDset), function(i){
        Get <- c(as.character(newDset[[i]]), as.character(samplevs[[i]]))
        ul <- unique(unlist(Get))
    })
      ## set the new levels for each column
    for(i in seq(newDset)) newDset[,i] <- factor(newDset[,i], newLevs[[i]])
      ## result
    newDset
}
```

**Your sample data :**

```
sampleData <- data.frame(abacus=factor(c("a","b","a","a","a")), 
                         montreal=factor(c("f","f","f","f","a")), 
                         boston=factor(c("z","y","z","z","q")))
dataset <- data.frame(florida=factor(c("e","q","z","d","b", "a")), 
                      montreal=factor(c("f","f","f","f","a", "a")), 
                      boston=factor(c("m","y","z","z","r", "f")), 
                      abacus=factor(c("a","b","z","a","a", "g")))
```

**Call** `findOthers()` **and view the result with the new factor levels :**

```
(new <- findOthers(newData = dataset))
#   abacus montreal boston
# 1      a        f  Other
# 2      b        f      y
# 3  Other        f      z
# 4      a        f      z
# 5      a        a  Other
# 6  Other        a  Other

as.list(new)
# $abacus
# [1] a     b     Other a     a     Other
# Levels: a b Other
# 
# $montreal
# [1] f f f f a a
# Levels: f a
# 
# $boston
# [1] Other y     z     z     Other Other     
# Levels: Other y z q     ## note the new level 'q', with no value in the column
```

Comment: Interesting. just to test it out, can you run a linear regression on the original 'sample data' dataframe (say `abacus~ montreal+boston`) and see if you can make predictions off the new dataset data, after it's been filtered out by your function? (I would, but am away from my machine right now).

Comment: I just ran a linear model `sampleData` and predicted using `new` at home, and it appears to work (with the caveat that we need to add `'Other'` to `sampleData` as a level in each of the columns in my example -- this is no problem as I already have `'Other'` in my real sample dataset.  One remaining loose end to tie up -- I see that although the factor names in `new` are the same as `SampleData`, the ordering of their levels is different -- will this give me erroneous results?

Comment: Possibly.  We could order them as they were and then append the new levels to the existing ones and give that a whirl.

Comment: Did you get a chance to test out your change?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't yet.  I have final exams currently.  Were you able to get anything useful from it?

Comment: I've been running ahead of a big deadline myself, but for now, I'll give you the bounty. Let's circle back on this in a week or two.

Comment: So I'm clear, the next thing we want to do is re-order the factors to match the originals (with the new ones appended), correct?

Answer (score 0):

To answer just the question you ask (rather than suggest what you might do instead). Here we have to make each column character, replace then re-factorise.

```
sampleData = sapply(sampleData, as.character)
sampleData = gsub("q", "other", sampleData)
sampleData = sapply(sampleData, as.factor)
```

This depends on "q" only inhabiting one column. Otherwise you just have to edit each column separately to get only the changes you want:

```
sampleData = sapply(sampleData, as.character)
sampleData$boston = gsub("q", "other", sampleData$boston)
sampleData = sapply(sampleData, as.factor)
```

However I think you should just filter the train and test data of these rows as they are so few 
they will make absolutely no difference to your model. Otherwise you're making it difficult.

```
summary(dataset)
dataset <- dataset[dataset$abacus!="z", ]
```

If the dataset is very very large and you are not doing this because of that then you may want to do this with something like the `dplyr` package and `filter` function.

Comment: Not sure this solution will work for me.  I'm more concerned with fixing `dataset` than `sampleData`; what's more is that `q` in sampleData may not be so infrequently occurring -- it just may not appear in the block of the total dataset that I'm pulling -- as I'm pulling it sequentially, not randomly.

Comment: Also, as I'm dealing with a lot of dependent factor variables, manually filtering the variables (which is what I'm doing currently) is a very time-consuming process that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
# Select and sort the columns of dataset as in sampleData
sampleData <- sampleData[, order(names(sampleData))]
dataset <- dataset[, colnames(sampleData)]

f <- function(dataset, sampleData, col) {
    # For a given column col, assign "Other" to all factor levels 
    # in dataset[col] that do not exist in sampleData[col].
    # If a factor level exists in sampleData[col] but not in dataset[col],
    # preserve it as a factor level.
    v <- factor(dataset[, col], levels = c(levels(sampleData[, col]), "Other"))
    v[is.na(v)] <- "Other"
    v
}

# Apply f to all columns of dataset
l <- lapply(colnames(dataset), function(x) f(dataset, sampleData, x))

res <- data.frame(l) # Format into a data frame
colnames(res) <- colnames(dataset) # Assign the names of dataset
dataset <- res # Assign the result to dataset
```

You can test as follows

```
> dataset[, "boston"]
[1] Other y     z     z     Other Other
Levels: q y z Other
> dataset[, "montreal"]
[1] f f f f a a
Levels: a f Other
> dataset[, "abacus"]
[1] a     b     Other a     a     Other
Levels: a b Other
```